# Always use a static import after first use

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I use certain static imports, I would like them to automatically be imported the first time I use them.

Say for example I am writing a class that uses the `Objects.requireNonNull` method.

I write something like this, and the auto-import for `Objects` gets added:

```java
import java.util.Objects;

public class StackOverflow {

    private final String s;

    public StackOverflow(String s) {
        this.s = Objects.requireNonNull(s);
    }
}
```

I then scroll over to the method, and select the **Add static import** option

[image: IntelliJ add static import]

Which transforms my code into this:

```java
import java.util.Objects;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

public class StackOverflow {

    private final String s;

    public StackOverflow(String s) {
        this.s = requireNonNull(s);
    }
}
```

I then have to clean up the original import for `java.util.Objects`, since I now have the method I want statically imported. I have to do this for every class that I do this with, and each time I want to add a static import (say if I wanted to use Guava's `Preconditions.checkArgument` or another common static import).

Is there any way to configure which methods should always be statically imported if they are used without using the `*` imports?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to auto import static imports what I do to avoid writing the class name is just write the method that I want to call, in your example `requireNotNull()` and then hit alt + enter which will then give you an option to add your static import.

FYI: I am not sure if you are aware of IntelliJ's [auto import](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/editor-auto-import.html) feature shown here:[image: auto import].

If not I would definitely recommend checking it out. I have not experienced it auto importing static imports but it may make your life easier in general.